# Error while installing Google App Engine SDK in eclipse 3.7

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, installation

I am trying to install the Google App Engine SDK in eclipse 3.7(Indigo) and i keep gettin the following error which is shown in the picture. I am using Windows 7. Could anyone direct me as to what to do to get over with this.
[image]

Comment: Some people who commented on [this](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2011/06/gpe-support-for-eclipse-indigo-37.html) blog post had similar problem because of their anti virus. If you have one try to turn it off and then install the plugin.

Comment: i have none installed in my pc

Comment: I had a lot of problems trying to install GAE plugin for Eclipse 3.7. In the end I just downloaded a clean install of GAE and installed the GAE plugin from a local repository (extracted zip) instead of an online repository. Worked for me..